# React.js how to update reset my navbar when changing url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have created a navbar with items but I cannot find a way to reset the navbar when changing of URL.

NAV-item.jsx (this is where I can click on the button to make my navbar appear or disappear)

```
function NavItem (props) {
    const [open,setOpen] = useState(false);
    return(
       
        <li className='nav-item'>
            <a 
            
            className='icon-button'
            onClick= {() => setOpen(!open)}> 
            {props.icon}
            </a>

            {open && props.children}
                
        </li>
           
       
    )

}
```

Directory.jsx (where my links are I tried to do history.push but I received an undefined error)

```
class Directory extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            Page1: PagesPrimaire,
            Page2: PagesSecondaire
            
        };
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className='menu-item'>
            {
                this.state.Page1.map(({id,title,linkUrl,history,match}) =>(
                    
                        <Link key={id} 
                        className='menu-item'
                        //to={`${linkUrl}`}
                        onClick = {() => history.push(this.state.Page1.linkUrl)}
                        >{title}</Link>
                    
                )
                )
            }
            
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default withRouter(Directory);
```

DropdownMenu.jsx (my navbar and some CSStransition tricks)

```
function DropdownMenu () {
    const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState('main');
   

    


    const DropdownItem = (props) =>
        
        (
            
                <a 
                className='menu-item' 
                onClick={()=>props.goToMenu && setActiveMenu(props.goToMenu)}>
                
                    {props.children}
                </a>
        
        )
    
    return (
        <div className='dropdown'>
            <CSSTransition 
            in={activeMenu === 'main' } 
            unmountOnExit 
            timeout={500}
            classNames='menu-primary'
            >
                <div className='menu'>
                <Directory/>
                <DropdownItem goToMenu='connexion'>Devenir Membre/connexion</DropdownItem>
                
                </div>
            </CSSTransition>
            <CSSTransition 
            in={activeMenu === 'connexion' } 
            unmountOnExit 
            timeout={500}
            classNames='menu-secondary'
            >
                <div className='menu'>
                <DropdownItem goToMenu='main'><img src={Leftarrow} className='arrow' alt=''></img></DropdownItem>
                
                    
                </div>
            </CSSTransition>
        
        </div>

    )

}
export default DropdownMenu;
```

Right now I can make the navbar appear and disappear by clicking a button but I cannot make it disappear when I change of Url.

Thank a lot,

Comment: if navbar is simple, make multiple navbar components based on pages, if you want to check some details like if user is logged in or not and show navbar accordingly, you can pass props to navbar component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @kritiz enter a navabar for each of the route and navigate to the one you need or use the same one and use props to decide what to do there is not other way as far as I know.
the only two version  I know is:
1.outside of switch
2.inside of each component with props to decied what to do in the nav